# "I don't like when you do something" or "I don't like when you are doing something"?

Tags: grammar, present-continuous, present-simple

Tell me please which tense I have to use in the following sentence.

> I don't like it when you **are sticking out**/**you stick out** your tongue.

I sometimes hear natives use the present continuous, even though the people weren't doing a certain action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither sentence is formed idiomatically, but (if rephrased) either tense is fine.

> I don't like it when you are sticking out your tongue.

This means you don't like it when I am in engaged in the activity of sticking out my tongue. For instance, possibly it makes my face look strange.

> I don't like it when you stick out your tongue.

This means you don't like it when I *do* stick out my tongue. It's not talking about the process as I'm in the middle of it necessarily, just the overall action itself. For instance, you might think it's rude.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd go with present simple. I'd also add an *it*:

> I don't like **it** when you **do** that.

The present continuous sounds fine, I just wouldn't use it here.

> I don't like it when you **are doing** that.

It seems like it puts a lot of emphasis on the instances themselves.

I don't, however, know what you mean by "stick your tongue". Did you mean "stick your tongue *out*"?